Rename tag:theory-of-the-mind
The existing tag theory-of-the-mind is a typo in the context it is used; the correct phrase is theory of mind. I suggest the tag be renamed.

Thanks @BryanKrause, I had noticed this as well, but needed a kick to actually do something about it.  Renamed.
